# Customize html element by its class and id

Tags: html

I am trying to modify [this](https://github.com/536uriel/nodejs-calendar) project to show me some dates with colors, but i dont know how should i edit a specific element, lets say with id="3" what is inside the div with id ="March". Until now in all my atempts i only succeded coloring all divs with id="3".
So my question is how do i modify the proprietes of an element with id="3" && id="March"?

Comment: Why don't you show us some of your attempts so we can help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target a div within a div do this:

```
<div id="3">
    <div id="March"></div>
</div>

#3 #March {
    color: purple;
}
```

Also try to use reasonable variable names in a camelCase naming convention.

Comment: True, using CSS for coloring is definitely the better approach than using Javascript.

Comment: but i need to take a json file and from there to change the color of individual divs

Comment: I guess I would need more specifics. @FlorinBaciu

Comment: from the server i get a json file and depending on this json file i need to change the color of diferent divs on this calenfar @berkobienb

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) for this.
In your case:

```
let march = document.getElementById('March')
let third_of_march = document.getElementById('3')
```

A small tip: IDs should be unique. The DOM API only returns one element. You should use classes in your use-case. This would make it even more simple.

```
let every_third_day = document.getElementsByClassName('3')
```

You can simply iterate over all elements and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: hi , i maked this function based on your answer : function colorEvents(){
        let march = document.getElementById('March');
        let third_of_march = march.getElementById('3');
        third_of_march.style.color = "blue";
} but i get this error: (index):6 Uncaught TypeError: march.getElementById is not a function

Comment: I fixed this problem. Look at my edit. It should be `document` instead of `march`